# Only some columns in an excel table are autofilling with formulas. For others i am having to manually drag the formula from above

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have this excel table where when i insert new rows into a table (at the bottom) some columns automatically are getting the formula from above and for other i have to manually drag the formula.

Its ok; but it would be nice to have the formula autopopulate in all the columns. Can anyone guess what could be wrong?

Comment: Without the actual formula posted here, we won't be able to help you.

Comment: I have been able to simplify the sheet so i can post here (file uploaded at [http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=55039860556771551875][1] since looks like i cant direclty upload the file here). If you copy the cells F18 to F20 and paste it in F21; it will create 3 new rows in the sheet for example. And now if you look to the right, formulas in column G and I are copied down to the new rows but columns H and J remain blank. 

[excel problem][2]


  [1]: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=55039860556771551875
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dABTX.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My work-around solution to this is is as follows:

1. copy one of the formulas in the non-filling column to a holding cell
2. delete all the entries in the column in the table.
3. copy back the formula to the **first** cell in the column in the table.

AFAIK Excel table's can develop a glitch that stops the auto-fill down from working.  I'm not sure why this happens.

My work-around is equivalent to turn-it-off-and-turn-it-on-again.  It has worked reliably for me.

---

BTW: I have had slightly different issues with tables but in my case it was filling an old formula.  - see [excel-table-inserting-old-formula-in-new-rows-how-can-i-reset-to-the-new-formula](https://superuser.com/questions/1229050/excel-table-inserting-old-formula-in-new-rows-how-can-i-reset-to-the-new-formul).

Comment: Thanks tjejojyj. For your problem, i am thinking maybe there is a hidden row or something that the formula is not getting deleted from and is showing up. How will it otherwise remember an old formula?

Comment: As far as I tell Excel stores the default formulas in a hidden register, rather than taking one row as the prototype.   For whatever reason, such as mixing formulas with values, the update of this hidden register stops happening.